# using wget to download log file every 5 mins & detect changes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff, wget

i am writing a bash script to accomplish the following.

1. script runs wget every five minutes to download a small log from a static url.
2. script uses diff to see if there are any new entries made to the log file (new entries are made at the end of log file).
3. if new log entries are found - extract the new entries to a new file, format them properly, send me an alert, return to #1.
4. if no new log entries are found, go back to #1.

```
wget "https://url-to-logs.org" -O new_log
if diff -q new_log old_log; then
echo "no new log entries to send."
else
echo "new log entries found, sending alert."
diff -u new_log old_log > new_entries

#some logic i have to take the output of "new_entries", properly format the text and send the alert.

rm -rf old_log new_entries
cp new_log old_log
rm -rf new_log
fi
```

there is one additional thing - every night at midnight the server hosting the logs deletes all entries and displays a blank file until new log entries are made for the new day.

i guess i could always run a cron job at midnight to run "rm -rf" and "touch" the old_log file, but curious if an easier way to do this exists.

thanks in advance for any/all input and help.

Comment: A simple hack is to check for number of lines in the new file and compare with the last or a bit harder - parse if a date/time header is present with log lines.

Comment: Do your logs include timestamps?

Comment: yes, they include timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

If your logs are not rotating - i.e. the old log is guaranteed to be the prefix of the new log, you can just use `tail` to get the new suffix - something like this:

```bash
tail -n+$(( $(wc -l old_log) + 1 )) new_log > new_entries
```

If there are no new lines in `new_log`, the `new_entries` file will be empty, which you can check using `stat` or some other way.

If your logs are rotating, you should first use `grep` to check if the last line from the old log exists in the new log, and if not - assume the entire new log is new:

```bash
if ! egrep -q "^$(tail -n1 old_log)\$" new_log; then cat new_log > new_entries; fi
```